# App-wide Context Menu

Tags: c#, contextmenu

I have created a context menu for a text-box in my .NET application, and it works great.  Now I would like to use that same context-menu for all text-boxes in my application.  Currently, I am using code like the following to work with the existing functionality:

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
        // Disable Undo if CanUndo property returns false
        if (mainTextBox.CanUndo)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Items["Undo"].Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Items["Undo"].Enabled = false;
        }
}
```

My question is how do I go about converting this code so that all text-boxes can use the same code, rather than rewriting this over and over again for all text-box instances.  I have assigned the same contextmenu to all of the text boxes, but more specifically, how do I pass the name of the calling text-box into the function?  I was hoping it would be simple like perhaps:

```
// Disable Undo if CanUndo property returns false
if (this.CanUndo)
{
   contextMenuStrip1.Items["Undo"].Enabled = true;
}
else
{
   contextMenuStrip1.Items["Undo"].Enabled = false;
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: See if you can develop custom textbox control and implement this context menu functionality. Replace your built-in textbox control with custom textbox control.

Comment: I've done that already for a single text-box.  I need to know how to expand it to all text-boxes that have the context menu assigned to it. Now I need to somehow pass the active text-box's (name?) to the function.

Comment: No one has any ideas here to create an app-wide context menu?